# how can i get the certain value on the top of query result by sort?

Tags: mysql

i have table with status column

```
CREATE TABLE movies
(
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
status int NOT NULL
);
```

status could be between 1 and 4 
and i want to sort the result by status

i can easily sort my query by `status` `asc` and `desc` and get the rows with 1 and 4 as value on the top

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl order by `status` ASC";
```

but how can i get 2 and 3 on the top of result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from tbl
order by case when status in (2, 3) then 0 else 1 end, 
    `status`
```

Comment: @max: The `CASE` statement generates an artificial sort column. When the `status` is 2 or 3, the `CASE` returns 0, which will sort before 1 (`ASC` is the default behaviour). Then the rows are sorted by `status`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where status IN (2,3) order by `status` ASC
UNION
SELECT * FROM tbl where status IN (1,4) order by `status` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` (as RedFilter's answer) or the **[`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_field)** function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
ORDER BY FIELD(status, 2, 3, 1, 4)    --- the order you prefer
```